# extract from {raster} package using excessive memory

Tags: r, memory, extract, raster

I have been using the `extract` function from the `raster` package to extract data from raster files using an area defined by shapefiles. However, I am having problems with the amount of memory that this process is now requiring. I do have a large number of shapefiles  (~1000). The raster files are large (~1.6gb)

My process is:

```
shp <- mclapply(list.files(pattern="*.shp",full.names=TRUE), readShapePoly,mc.cores=6)
ndvi <- raster("NDVI.dat")
mc<- function(y) {
temp <- gUnionCascaded(y)
extract <- extract(ndvi,temp)
mean <- range(extract, na.rm=T )[1:2]
leng <- length(output)
}
output <- lapply(shp, mc)
```

Are there any changes I can make to reduce the memory load? I tried loading fewer shapefiles which worked for about 5 min before the memory spiked again. Its a quad core computer 2.4ghz with 8gb ram

Comment: Don't load them all in at once, just loop over the shapefiles individually. (Sheesh). -1 since you have not demonstrated the relative memory usage, though you claim extract() is to blame.

Comment: The use of mclapply is totally bogus btw, since the files are all on the same disk.

Comment: what is output in mc()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this (untested):

```
## Clearly we need these packages, and their dependencies
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
shpfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.shp",full.names=TRUE)
ndvi <- raster("NDVI.dat")
## initialize an object to store the results for each shpfile
res <- vector("list", length(shpfiles))
names(res) <- shpfiles
## loop over files
for (i in seq_along(shpfiles)) {
  ## do the union
  temp <- gUnionCascaded(shpfiles[i])
  ## extract for this shape data (and don't call it "extract")
  extracted <- extract(ndvi,temp)
  ## further processing, save result
  mean <- range(extracted, na.rm = TRUE )[1:2]
  res[[i]] <- mean  ## plus whatever else you need
}
```

It's not at all clear what the return value of mc() above is meant to be, so I ignore it. This will be far more memory efficient and fast than what you tried originally. I doubt it's worth using parallel stuff at all here.

Comment: The `extract` function is actually internally multi-core when using polygons. You don't need to do anything to take advantage of this fact, other than `require( parallel ); beginCluster( detectCores()-1 )`. When extracting across 1000 polygons you may find a significant speed advantage by doing this (but this question concerns memory, not speed).