# Extracting data from a raster brick using multiple threads

Tags: r, multicore, raster, r-raster

I'm extracting data from a raster file. I need to extract only a random sample of 1000 cells, like so:

```
pr <- brick(filename[i], varname=var[i], na.rm=T)
cells <- sampleRandom(pr[[1]], 1000, cells=T)
prvals <- pr[cells[,1]] #Equivalent of extract(pr, cells[,1])
```

I'd like to use more cores to speed up the process, like so:

```
beginCluster(4)
pr <- brick(filename[i], varname=var[i], na.rm=T)
cells <- sampleRandom(pr[[1]], cnsample, cells=T)
prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1]))
endCluster()
```

However, the `clusterR()` line is throwing all kind of errors at me, such as:

> > prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1])) Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    4 nodes produced
> >     errors; first error: argument is of length zero
> >
> > prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1])) Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    2 nodes produced
> >     errors; first error: argument is of length zero
> >
> > prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1])) Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    3 nodes produced
> >     errors; first error: argument is of length zero
> >
> > prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1])) Error in clusterR(pr, extract, args = list(cells[, 1])) : cluster error In
> >     addition: There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> >
> > prvals <- clusterR(pr, extract, args=list(cells[,1])) Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    3 nodes produced
> >     errors; first error: argument is of length zero In addition: Warning
> >     message: closing unused connection 9
> >     (/tmp/R_raster_tmp/afantini/raster_tmp_2014-11-28_131043_31528.gri)

What's wrong?

EDIT:
I tried the examples in the `raster` documentation and they work on another machine, on this they don't. So there is a deeper problem with this machine. Package snow is correctly installed. R is at latest version.

Comment: Isn't `raster::extract` already multi-core?

Comment: @PauloCardoso Not always. The manual says: "The use of the cluster is automatic in these functions: projectRaster, resample and in extract
when using polygons." Also, looking at `top`, it's evident that it's using just one core.

Comment: Please see [this particular example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694355/extract-from-raster-package-using-excessive-memory).

Comment: @PauloCardoso Would you please elaborate? I have no memory problem in this case, and I'm CPU bottlenecked: CPU (1 core only) stays at 100% all the time during the extraction. `extract()` *is* multi thread only when using polygons, which I'm not. I do not understand what's wrong with my code.